# C++ Canonical Project Structure, can't find headers

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm fairly new to C++ and writing makefiles. I'm trying to compile a C++ project with the "canonical" structure described [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1204r0.html) with a makefile. I'm running into a problem where the compilation is failing because it can't find the headers due to using <brackets> instead of "quotes" when including the headers.

How do I tell the compiler where to find the headers in the project?

Comment: Which headers are in brackets, and which in quotes? The headers you define should use quotes, while system and standard headers should use brackets.

Comment: Not according to that link which suggests that all headers should be included with brackets. I think this avoid unintended includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use the `-I` option, followed by a relative or absolute path to the directory where the headers are.

For example:

```
gcc -c src/foo.c -o obj/foo.o -I src
```

(However, compiler options are not part of the C++ standard, so it depends on what compiler you are using, and you did not say.)